# Don`t able to save token from RestSharp OAuth request Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, oauth, windows-phone-8.1, restsharp, trello

I trying to get Request Token from Trello with RestSharp. I got token only in request thread, but dont able to save it in variable of my app.
 There some code:

```
    private async void GetToken()
    {

        app.Client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(app.ConsumerKey, app.ConsumerSecret);
        var request = new RestRequest("OAuthGetRequestToken", Method.POST);
        app.Client.ExecuteAsync(request, HandleResponse);

    }

    private void HandleResponse(IRestResponse restResponse)
    {
        var Response = restResponse;
        MessageBox.Show(Response.Content);
        QueryString qs = new QueryString(Response.Content);
        app.OAuthToken = qs["oauth_token"];
        app.OAuthTokenSecret = qs["oauth_token_secret"];
        app.Verifier = qs["verifier"];
        MessageBox.Show(app.OAuthToken);       //got token here, but after
        MessageBox.Show(app.OAuthTokenSecret); //I don`t have anything in this variables
    }
```

Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Solution to this problem is to create class that enable me to create synchronous request.
There is code of this class:

```
public static class RestClientExtensions
{
    public static Task<IRestResponse> ExecuteTask(this IRestClient client, RestRequest request)
    {
        var TaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
        client.ExecuteAsync(request, (response, asyncHandle) =>
        {
            if (response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Error)
                TaskCompletionSource.SetException(response.ErrorException);
            else
                TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(response);
        });
        return TaskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

And now my code looks like this:

```
private async void GetToken()
    {

        app.Client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForRequestToken(app.ConsumerKey, app.ConsumerSecret);
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("OAuthGetRequestToken", Method.POST);
        IRestResponse restResponse = await app.Client.ExecuteTask(request);
        HandleResponse(restResponse);
        GetAccesToken();
    }

    private void HandleResponse(IRestResponse response)
    {
        var Response = response;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Response.Content);
        QueryString qs = new QueryString(Response.Content);
        app.OAuthToken = qs["oauth_token"];
        app.OAuthTokenSecret = qs["oauth_token_secret"];
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(app.OAuthToken);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(app.OAuthTokenSecret);
    }
```

And after the method HandleResponse(response); performed, I have the token and token secret in my app class.
I still believe that there must be better solution for this problem, but it is the only one that I know.